# Multiple IPSEC VPN to AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, vpn, cisco, ipsec, amazon-vpc

I am completely new to AWS and I am trying to configure the VPC we have with 2 VPN connections to our 2 datacenters. I am having some trouble wrapping my head around the networking end of it so I want to confirm if this is feasible before I bang my head against it more.

We want to have an EC2 instance running within this VPC, and that the instance needs to be able to talk to both datacenters. So far, I have created a VPC, which gave me 3 Subnets based on Availability Zones for the region we picked. I also created an Internet Gateway. Added both of our Cisco firewalls as Customer Gateways, and respective Virtual Private Gateways.

Comment: Suggest you read the excellent documentation, follow the instructions, then either contact AWS support (it's $30 a month for developer support) or bring any concrete problems here to help.

Comment: Were you able to resolve this? I am also looking to have the same Architecture..

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to say is that you are able to connect an AWS VPC to multiple customer networks. I have tried to upload a document with a diagram in it but its not working so here is a link to a good diagram:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/images/Branch_Offices_diagram.png

The best place I find for documentation is the AWS documentation site, here is a link to the VPN section:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_VPN.html#VPN

Answer (score 0):

Can see you've already been given some pointers on where to start but thought I'd add some points to note when it comes to VPNs in AWS in general.

- VPN tunnel can only be brought up from your remote end (in your case, your Cisco ASAs). The EC2 instances won't be able to bring the tunnel up
- Within the config for the ASA, you can only specify one local and one remote network (the remote network most likely being your VPC subnet). You may need to expand your subnet on your local network to achieve this or set up some NAT rules before it passes over the VPN.